# Azure Function App Publish Target Missing in Visual Studio

Tags: azure, azure-functions, publish, azure-function-app-proxy

I'm trying to publish an Azure Function to already deployed Azure Function App, which is in my subscription.

But Publish target for the Function app is missing.

This is a newly created Function and all other existing function has the publish target visible.

Do I need to configure something on the subscription side or the function .csproj to enable publish target?

One that has azure resource as publish target is running on 1.x runtime.

One that does not have azure resource as publish target is running on 2.x runtime

[image: Ones that does not show azure function as target]

[image: One that shows azure function as target]

Comment: what are you seeing? A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann images are added now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding reference to "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Function" to note that it's an Azure Function fixed the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue in VS 2019 but upgrading "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Function" not solve.

Answer (score -1):

For the latest version (VS20212 and Azure Function 3+) - adding references to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions. There is one extra s in the package name. My article has added more details for reference:
[Resolve - Azure Function App Publish Specific Target Not Existing in VS2019](https://kontext.tech/column/cloud-azure/771/resolve-azure-function-app-publish-specific-target-not-existing-in-vs2019)